# User task in job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Good morning,

I appreciate can help me

I currently have a jenkins job in which I set by user tasks to perform in the
"Post build task", therefore all these configurations are executed after the
user compiles the project.

But I need the same "job" I may have settings "Post build task" and also to
make a configuration for a specific user to run a script or additional tasks
without recompiling the project.

Thank you can help me with some idea

Comment: I can't figure out what you want exactly. Maybe you know someone who can help with your english?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to obtain build result from upstream build. Then you can operate these artifacts without having to rebuild the whole project again. Also you can setup job triggers to automatically start downstream job after upstream job is finished successfully